# query on oracle database using kafka messaging system

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I have an oracle database which is a data warehouse and I'm using a kafka messaging system to exchange messages in my system. In my disaster recovery solution I'm going to query on an oracle database using kafka connect and then copy the queried messages to a H2 database. Do you guys have a solution to query on an oracle database using kafka connect? I'm not going to use any third party software solution like "confluent" and I prefer not to use kafka APIs!

Please HELPPP!!

Comment: apache-flume? https://www.toadworld.com/platforms/oracle/w/wiki/11524.streaming-oracle-database-table-data-to-apache-kafka

Comment: Can I perform a simple select query using flume??

Comment: Apache Flume was Ideal for me and I used it in order to bulk insert from a database to another. Thanks golezTrol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are already using Kafka then Kafka connect would be ideal for your situation. You can read from an Oracle DB and make it available on the Kafka topic using  [Kafka connect source](https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/connect-jdbc/docs/source_connector.html#quickstart) and then configure a [Kafka Connect Sink](https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/connect-jdbc/docs/sink_connector.html#quickstart)  to source it to your H2 database.

Comment: Thanks dude but I need to tell you that I did the job using flume without any need to kafka-connect. Because I just wanted to use something endorsed by apache and as you know kafka-connect is  licensed by confluent which I assume is a third party. It was amazing. I will give you accurate details to you in an answer in the near future!